# UIGestureRecognizer didn't respond swift 3.0

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

When I pan on the view it didn't react. The following code shows how I setup the gesture recognizer. What's wrong with my code?

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizerForSetCardFace)
    }

    var gestureRecognizerForSetCardFace: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSetGesture(gesture:)))
        recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        return recognizer
    }()

     @objc func handleSetGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        print("pan")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any subview with an higher z-index above your main view?

Comment: You should use the `viewDidLoad()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you need to add -

- Add `Lazy var` for your gesture.

> Lazy properties are useful when the initial value for a property is
>   dependent on outside factors whose values are not known until after an
>   instance’s initialization is complete.

```
lazy var gestureRecognizerForSetCardFace: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSetGesture(gesture:)))
        recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        return recognizer
    }()
```

- Add gesture recogniser in `viewdidLoad`

> Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizerForSetCardFace)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding `loadView`. That should only be overridden if you actually create a view and assign it to `self.view`.

Change your code to override `viewDidLoad` instead.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizerForSetCardFace)
}
```